# Transferring a .docx text page to Excel without losing the formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, pdf

Given: an new automated quote template in Excel; an old quote in docx with an appendix written in lines of text, numerated lists and small tables.
Goal: transfer the appendix text from docx to Excel without losing too much formatting and as quickly as possible. I *then* want to export the whole Excel book as a pdf without needing to combine separate pdf documents.

What would be the easiest way to transfer this text to Excel?
Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: It is unclear if you want to convert it to PDF or to excel. Note that word includes a function to export a document to PDF

Comment: Hello and welcome! Have you tried copying the contents of the document into Word and using Paste Special (CTRL+ALT+V) to paste it into an Excel sheet?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @mashuptwice I want to transfer the data to excel to then easily convert the whole thing to pdf whenever I need it. Otherwise I would need to merge the files, etc.

Comment: @JohnSUN Hi, thank you. I'll try that.